# Separate Data From Gyroscope Serial Port, Python

Tags: python

I have a Bluetooth gyroscope that I only want accelerometer data from. When I open the port the data will come in as a single, jumbled stream, right? How do I grab the data that I want? I want to simulate a keypress if acceleration is over a certain value, if that helps.[image]

Comment: Does the gyroscope come with any documentation? You need to find out what is in that stream of data. What is the protocol? 
What is the make and model number?

Comment: It's a JY61 Witmotion 6-Axis Bluetooth gyroscope. It outputs as TTL serial, or via bluetooth. If I want to use anything other than the bundled software, will I need to use a USB-to-serial? I'm sorry I'm such a novice.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I just updated the OP with an image I found in the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data packet is 11 bytes, read 11 bytes at a time from the port, then parse the message. Note, you may want to read 1 byte at a time until you get a start-message byte (`0x55`) then read the following 10.

```
# data is a byte array, len = 11
def parse_packet(data):
    # Verify message
    if data[0] == 0x55 and data[1] == 0x51 and len(data) == 11:
        # Verify checksum
        if ((sum(data) - data[10]) & 0xFF) == data[10]:
            g = 9.8    # Gravity
            parsed = {}
            parsed["Ax"] = ((data[3] << 8) | data[2]) / 32768.0 * 16 * g
            parsed["Ay"] = ((data[5] << 8) | data[4]) / 32768.0 * 16 * g
            parsed["Az"] = ((data[7] << 8) | data[6]) / 32768.0 * 16 * g
            # Temp in in degrees celsius
            parsed["Temp"] = ((data[9] << 8) | data[8]) / 340.0 + 36.53
            return parsed
    return None
```

The one thing you need to verify is the checksum calculation. I couldn't find it in the manual. The other calculations came from the manual I found here: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1303256/Elecmaster-Jy-61-Series.html?page=9#manual